# Why would anyone use a bracket buy instead of a trailing stop loss?

Tags: stocks, investing

From my understanding of how these bracket orders work you simply buy-in and then set a stop-limit above and below.  This assumes you want to get out at some set position above the stock's current price.  Give a scenario where it wouldn't make sense to simply ride all the upswing until the stock gives back a certain percent of its value - particularly if the % was chosen carefully so as not to trigger unnecessary sells with a highly volatile stock, as with a trailing stop-loss.

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but what is the difference between setting a limit above "to get out at some set position above the stock's current price" and the condition of your requested scenario regarding "simply [riding] all the upswing until the stock gives back a certain percent of its value"? Are you drawing a distinction between a limit order and a manual 'watching brief'?

Comment: Well, a trailing stop order can be set-up as soon as the buy market order goes through and you own the stock.  In this way you also aren't having to watch the stock; it'll just sell once the stock value recedes a certain percentage from its high point.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the take-profit limit order, not the stop-loss.

Comment: Re-reading your comment - you're talking about a limit order on the high side that triggers only after the stock has breached the limit and falls back to it, right? That still looks like *automatic* vs *manual*, where the automatic version (from the bracket buy) isn't open to human error. But your question's title seems to imply the opposite - that the trailing stop loss is preferable. In that case, your comment would seem to answer your question.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm confused as I've never used a bracket order before and I'm just now learning about them.  Looking more into it, it appears that the two secondary sell orders in a "one triggers one cancels the other" or OTOCO order can be set to various types of orders - such as the aforementioned trailing stop loss.  So I suppose your initial O could be a market buy, your second O could be trailing stop loss sell (above current price) and the third O could be a stop limit sell.